# Is there a way to know where on page something is placed html

Tags: html, rcurl

Let's say I want to know if a call-to-action (like a fill-out form) is placed "within the fold" meaning it is visible as soon as you load the page without scrolling.  Is there something in the html that would allow me to know this?

Comment: Fairly easy to calculate with javascript based on the size of the window and the coordinates of the element.

Comment: Use PhantomJS or Selenium. RCurl is not the tool for this since it is not a browser...it doesn't actually render anything so it's essentially impossible to use it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start by reading up on the CSS [position attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).  Perhaps `position: fixed` is what you are looking for.  But it really depends on the remaining content of your site.

Comment: Basically I need to load the html using say RCurl and analyze the text for a variety of reasons.  But it would be great to rapidly read in the raw html from each page and quantify whether or not a call-to-action is in the non-scrolling position.